# Event Grid-triggered Function Keeps Triggering After Function Successfully Runs?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I have an Azure Function triggered by Event Grid Events. Event Grid Events are created only when a blob is uploaded to a Storage Account.

This is now deployed and working well although for some reason, the Function keeps getting triggered by the same event even though it successfully processed?

**Example:**

- Yesterday, 8 successful tests; all good:
  [image]
- Today I review the logs, and the function has continued to execute!
- Error: "Blob does not exist"
- I deleted the blob after last test yesterday. Why is the Event Grid still firing?
  [image]

**Code snippet:**

```
def main(event: func.EventGridEvent):

        result = json.dumps({
            'id' : event.id,
            'data' : event.get_json(),
            'topic' : event.topic,
            'subject' : event.subject,
            'event_type' : event.event_type
        })

        logging.info('EventGrid trigger processing an event: %s', result)

        credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

        download_start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        logging.info(f'######## Starting downloading blob from storage at ' + str(download_start_time) + ' ########')

        # =============================
        # Download blob from storage container:
        # =============================

        blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(event.get_json()["url"], credential)
        blob_data = blob_client.download_blob().readall()
        blob_byte_stream = io.BytesIO(blob_data)
```

**EDIT 1: This is still happening, this time a bit different.**

- Now, the EventGrid keeps firing after SUCCESSFULLY passing messages and the Function running

**How do I debug this?**

[image]

Comment: It seems something wrong with your stack. Are you using virtual environment? And can you post some details like your testing code?

Comment: I'm using a `.venv` in my local dev env, but this Function is hosted and being triggered in Azure, not locally. I do not have any testing code to share. The Function has now ceased to trigger, but I'd like to understand how to debug this issue in the future.

Comment: Okay...Since we could not see your code, I'm not convinced the reason. But I saw there is a _download.py file, are you trying to download the blob already deleted? Maybe you should check that.@ericOnline

Comment: Does that help @DorisLv? This is the only part of the Function that downloads the blob from storage. After the Function successfully triggers via EventGrid message, why would it continue to trigger? To me, the **trigger** is the issue, not the `BlobClient`.

Comment: I faced the same problems sometimes, when the functions doesn't succeed immediately. Event Grid provides at least once delivery guarantees so subscribers of the events should account for duplicates, see [Event Grid message delivery and retry](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry).

Comment: Yeah, in this case, it seems to be a single test.csv file uploaded to a certain Container. Keeps retrying. Seems to be pretty random. Is there a cache or something I can clear out for the EventGrid trigger?

Comment: for test purposes: set the *maxDeliveryAttempts = 3* and *dead-lettering*, which give you more details about the failed delivering, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#retry-schedule-and-duration

Comment: This is still happening. Its quite annoying (especially because we are charged per Function call). Why does EventGrid keep firing after successfully delivering messages?

Comment: I finally figured out what the issue was...using the `BlobClient.from_blob_url` method worked fine when testing blob uploads using Azure Storage Explorer. But when using Azure Data Factory, the `data.url` property in the EventGrid message is not the actual blob url (contained `dfs` instead of `blob`). Oddly enough, after I brought this issue to Microsoft Support attention, a new `blobUrl` property was added to EventGrid `data` object. I simply changed "url" to "blobUrl" and the method succeeded. (I also improved the error handling of the Python code to accommodate such errors in the future.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what the issue was...using the `BlobClient.from_blob_url` method worked fine when testing blob uploads using Azure Storage Explorer. But when using Azure Data Factory, a different API is used and the `data.url` property in the EventGrid message is not the actual blob url (contained `dfs` instead of `blob`).

Oddly enough, soon after I brought this issue up to support team, a new `blobUrl` property was added to EventGrid `data` object.

In my code, I simply changed "url" to "blobUrl" and the method succeeded. (I also improved the error handling of the Python code to accommodate such errors in the future.)

**[Documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage#microsoftstorageblobcreated-event-data-lake-storage-gen2) EventGrid message (as of 12/10/2020):**

- No `blobUrl` property

```
[{
  "topic": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/Storage/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/my-storage-account",
  "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/my-file-system/blobs/new-file.txt",
  "eventType": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated",
  "eventTime": "2017-06-26T18:41:00.9584103Z",
  "id": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e069631",
  "data": {
    "api": "CreateFile",
    "clientRequestId": "6d79dbfb-0e37-4fc4-981f-442c9ca65760",
    "requestId": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e000000",
    "eTag": "\"0x8D4BCC2E4835CD0\"",
    "contentType": "text/plain",
    "contentLength": 0,
    "contentOffset": 0,
    "blobType": "BlockBlob",
    "url": "https://my-storage-account.dfs.core.windows.net/my-file-system/new-file.txt",
    "sequencer": "00000000000004420000000000028963",  
    "storageDiagnostics": {
    "batchId": "b68529f3-68cd-4744-baa4-3c0498ec19f0"
    }
  },
  "dataVersion": "2",
  "metadataVersion": "1"
}]
```

**Actual EventGrid message coming through now:**

- Notice `blobUrl` has been added to the schema

```
{
    "id": "long-string",
    "data": {
        "api": "CreateFile",
        "requestId": "long-string",
        "eTag": "0x8D89B4FF7150079",
        "contentType": "application/octet-stream",
        "contentLength": 0,
        "contentOffset": 0,
        "blobType": "BlockBlob",
        "blobProperties": [{
            "acl": [{
                "access": "u::rw,u:long-string:rwx,u:long-string:rwx,g::rx,g:long-string:rx,m::rw,o::",
                "permission": "0660",
                "owner": "long-string",
                "group": "$superuser"
            }]
        }],
        "blobUrl": "https://myfunction.blob.core.windows.net/container/20201208/730420201208080239.csv",
        "url": "https://myfunction.dfs.core.windows.net/container/20201208/730420201208080239.csv",
        "sequencer": "0000000000000000000000000000692c00000000000e1a99",
        "identity": "long-string",
        "storageDiagnostics": {
            "batchId": "long-string"
        }
    },
    "topic": "/subscriptions/long-string/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageAccount",
    "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/container/blobs/20201208/730420201208080239.csv",
    "event_type": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated"
}
```

**Another caveat here...notice the `Content-Length` in the message above**

- The `CreateFile` API is not the actual message which indicates the blob has been created.
- The `FlushWithClose` API is

There is a note in the docs about this. So I also had to setup an EventGrid Advanced Filter which only triggers when `FlushWithClose` events are generated (!)

[image]